# Daphne does not find *server* on production server

Tags: django, daphne

I am trying to use [django-eventstream](https://pypi.org/project/django-eventstream/) to implement SSE events. My code runs perfectly using `manage.py runserver` on the local PC. However, when I run:

```
daphne config.asgi:application
```

on the production server, I get the following error:

```
  File "./config/asgi.py", line 21, in <module>
    url(r'', get_asgi_application()),
  File "/home/bidforga/virtualenv/bfg/bfg_wag/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/asgi.py", line 12, in get_asgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/bidforga/virtualenv/bfg/bfg_wag/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/bidforga/virtualenv/bfg/bfg_wag/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/bidforga/virtualenv/bfg/bfg_wag/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/bidforga/virtualenv/bfg/bfg_wag/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/bidforga/virtualenv/bfg/bfg_wag/3.7/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'server'
```

This is my *config/asgi.py*

```
import os
import django
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.conf.urls import url
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import django_eventstream

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "server.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': URLRouter([
        url(r'^events/', AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(django_eventstream.routing.urlpatterns)
        ), { 'channels': ['test'] }),
        url(r'', get_asgi_application()),
    ]),
})
```

I assume it's looking for *server.settings* but I have no idea how to solve this